# INSERT INTO table SELECT & Append a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Take a look at my query:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (userId, workstationId, duration, actionType)
    SELECT userId, workstationId, duration
    FROM activeSessions
    WHERE workstationId = ?
```

The select statement doesn't contain enough data to push into `sessions` . I want to insert an actionType as well (as a parameter (`?`). That said, I need to append a column to the right of the result of the select statement in order for this to work. How is that done?

Comment: Same actionType, or different?

Comment: @jarlh different each time. I want this to be a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dummy values in mysql select:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (userId, workstationId, duration, actionType)
    SELECT userId, workstationId, duration, 'actionType' as actionType
    FROM activeSessions
    WHERE workstationId = ?
```

For different parameter you can also use select inside select query.

```
INSERT INTO sessions (userId, workstationId, duration, actionType)
        SELECT userId, workstationId, duration, 
        (select id from actionTypeTable where id = ?) as actionType
        FROM activeSessions
        WHERE workstationId = ?
```

Comment: OP wants different actionType values, as parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Will accept as soon as the time limit goes off. I guess I can set it up as a parameter?

Comment: @jarlh if it can be dummy data, it can be a parameter too

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your query resides in a procedure, you can add these parameters.

```
INSERT INTO sessions (userId, workstationId, duration, actionType)
    SELECT userId, workstationId, duration, @actionType
    FROM activeSessions
    WHERE workstationId = @workstationId
```